# Laravel checkbox always empty

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox, laravel-blade

I have a weird problem that I can't seem to solve. I have a checkbox:

```
{!! Form::checkbox('createDatabase', '1', true) !!}
```

When I submit my form it always gives me an empty string when it is checked.
Unless I submit my form and get a validation error on other field and I resubmit it, then I get '1'.

I already tried using true instead of one and some other values but nothing seems to work.

It's weird I have done this a lot of times before and I never had this before.

**Edit: controller code**

```
public function store(NewProjectRequest $request)
    {
        dd($request->createDatabase)
        //some more code over here but it's not related
    }
```

Comment: What does your code look like on the other side? Are you using a Request object?

Comment: I use a Request class for the validation and access everything through that class in my controller.

Comment: Could we see the code you have in your controller for this?

Comment: I updated my original post. I removed a lot of stuff because it's not related.

Comment: Try `$request->input('createDatabase')`.

Comment: Have you checked the code (and source code) to make sure there isn't another input with the name 'createDatabase' after your checkbox? What does your form view look like?

Comment: @StuartWagner I tried that but that gives me the same result.

Comment: @patricus I checked and double checked that, it's the only field with that name.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the following progression of code in your controller's store method:

```
    public function store(NewProjectRequest $request)
    {
        Database::create($request->all());
        return $database;
    }
```

The above assumes that this is a "Database" object you are creating that you have a model for.  The $request->all() is (as you may already know) how all of the input from your form is getting saved as a Database object.

Make sure you have set all of your input as mass assignable in your Model if you do things this way, though:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Database extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'createDatabase',
        'otherInputNames'
    ];
}
```

Comment: The progression of my code is not the problem, that works all fine. Only that one checkbox is always empty.

Comment: Can you post your HTML code for your forms and your Database Model?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your comments and help.

After a few hours of intense debugging I was able to solve the problem. It had not nothing to do with blade or my input fields and all that stuff.

My form is autocompleted on the first field, a unique code. Every key up (with debounce) I check if that code does exist in the database. If that field does not exist I empty all the field of my form, including the checkboxes apparently.

So by excluding the checkboxes on that call everything was solved.

Thanks again for all the input!